# How to remove Geo Tagging on image uploads, but not other EXIF data?

Tags: images, uploads

I want to strip the geotag information from the EXIF data in images that are uploaded.  We take photos at home and do not wish to publicly publish GPS coordinates to our home.  However there is useful EXIF data that we don't want to strip.

Is there a way to strip only geotag information from the EXIF data in images?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be automatically scrubbing that information on the stored files on my Wordpress installation.

Take a photo on your computer and check the lat and long information to see if it's present. If it is, Upload via the WP Uploader then download the images it makes off your SFTP. All mine seem to be scrubbed.

Am I wrong?

Comment: I was also under the impression the exif was scrubbed. I remember people in the photography space being upset about it a while back as it contained their copyright info.

Comment: I did this with mine and it was not the case (latest wordpress).  Make sure you check the _original_ file for exif info, not the resized ones that went through GD/IM processing.  If you are not using ImageMagick then you are right that WP scrubs the exif info for the files it converts (again not the original), but it's _all_ the exif info not just GPS coordinates.  That's a side effect of the GD library that WP uses by default, not an intentional thing (so could also change if GD behavior changed under the hood).  I wouldn't rely on this personally.